# In triangle $ABC$ prove that $\frac{1}{AD}=\frac{1}{AC}+\frac{1}{AB}$.

Tags: geometry

> In triangle $ABC$ measure of angle $A =120^\circ$ , $AD$ is angle bisector with $D$ on $BC$ prove that $$\frac{1}{AD}=\frac{1}{AC}+\frac{1}{AB}$$

I tried this question whole day but could not find any solution for this please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bisector divides the triangle into two sub-triangles. Use area formula (i.e. $[\triangle ABC] = \dfrac 12 ab \sin C$) three times to equate them (i.e.$[\triangle ABC] = [\triangle ABD] + [\triangle ACD]$ .

Since $\sin 120^0 = \sin 60^0$, the factors of sine will be cancelled leaving an expression in AB, AD and AC. Just simply re-arranging terms.

---

From $[\triangle ABC] = [\triangle ABD] + [\triangle ACD]$, we have 
$$\dfrac 12 (AB)(AC) \sin 120^0 = \dfrac {1}{2} (AB)(AD) \sin 60^0 + \dfrac {1}{2} (AD)(AC) \sin 60^0$$.

Since $\sin 120^0 = \sin 60^0$, we get $(AB)(AC) = (AB)(AD)  +  (AD)(AC)$.

Result follows after dividing both sides by $AB.AD.AC$.

Comment: Please tell me in deep

Comment: BY area formula, I mean $[\triangle ABC] = \dfrac 12 ab \sin C$.

Comment: $[\triangle ABC] = [\triangle ABD] + [\triangle ACD]$. See edited version.

Comment: I haven't understood please tell me in more deep as I am a school going student

Comment: More deeply please

Comment: @AtharvaShetty see the edited full version.

Comment: @AtharvaShetty If you haven't learnt the area formula, I can introduce a simpler version that does not rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here's an answer with a rough figure..

Let us call $\measuredangle ABC=x$

So $\measuredangle ACB=60^{\circ}-x$

Similarly $\measuredangle ADC=60^{\circ}+x$

and $\measuredangle ADB=120^{\circ}-x$

Note that $\sin(\measuredangle ADB)=\sin(120^{\circ}-x)=\sin(60^{\circ}+x)$

By Law  Of Sines 
$$\frac{\sin(\measuredangle ADB)}{AB}=\frac{\sin(\measuredangle ABD)}{AD}$$

Similarly,
$$\frac{\sin(\measuredangle ADC)}{AC}=\frac{\sin(\measuredangle ACD)}{AD}$$

Ading them and Noting that $\sin(\measuredangle ADB)=\sin(\measuredangle ADC)$ gives

$$\sin(\measuredangle ADC)(\frac{1}{AB}+\frac{1}{AC})=\frac{\sin(\measuredangle ABD)+\sin(\measuredangle ACD)}{AD}=\frac{\sin(x)+\sin(60^{\circ}-x)}{AD}=\frac{\sin(60^{\circ}+x)}{AD}=\frac{\sin(\measuredangle ADC)}{AD}$$
whih on simplifying gives

$$\frac{1}{AD}=\frac{1}{AC}+\frac{1}{AB}$$

Hope that helps ..

Comment: Your welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach without using trigonometry. All above answers use trigonometry , so I am presenting my solution -

[image]

In $Δ ABC, $ Observe that $\measuredangle BAD=\measuredangle DAC = 60° \Rightarrow \measuredangle EAB = 60°$

Now consider $ΔADC , AB $ is the external angle bisector of $\measuredangle A$

Property of external angle bisector ,

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{AD}{AC}=\dfrac{BD}{BC}\Rightarrow \dfrac{AC}{AD}=\dfrac{BD+DC}{BD}=1+\dfrac{DC}{BD} \cdots [1]$

In $ΔABC, AD$ is the angle bisector of $\measuredangle A,$

Property of internal angle bisector ,

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{AB}{AC}=\dfrac{BD}{DC} \Rightarrow \dfrac{AC}{AB}=\dfrac{DC}{BD}=\dfrac{AD}{AC}-1$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{AC}{AB}=\dfrac{AC}{AD}-1$

Rearranging ,

$\boxed{\dfrac{1}{AD}=\dfrac{1}{AC}+\dfrac{1}{AB}} $

Hence we are done! Upvote if it is useful $:)$